# TinyMCE dropdown appears off the Editor either top or bottom not with in the editor itself when using in vue-3

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to fix the top: -490.90px <div role="menu" style="top: -490.98px". But, when you click anyother place this values get overwritten by element.style. This is in a vuejs application. When I have a div tag above the rich text editor and when div tag.